# Add Individual Object in unlocked package

Tags: salesforcedx, packaging-2, individual, packaging

Does anyone know if Individual Object is supported in Unlocked Packages? 
I tried to look in the [list of available features](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm), 
similar to what is necessary for Person Accounts, but I did not find anything for Individuals.

I keep getting the error: **Individual: Invalid fullName, must end in a custom suffix**

How can I add it to my unlocked package?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature you can activate inside the scratch org definition file but it sits inside the OrgPreferences.

Have a look here in this answer to check out how to turn this on inside your repository:
[enable "Data Protection and Privacy" when creating scratch org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263928/enable-data-protection-and-privacy-when-creating-scratch-org/266221#266221)