# enable "Data Protection and Privacy" when creating scratch org

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, gdpr

Is there any way how to automatically enable "Data Protection and Privacy" option during creation of scratch org (in definition file)?

[image: Data Protection and Privacy]

I didn't found any mention about this metadata in Metadata API at all. Is it   already supported?

We have implemented some logic that is dependent on Individual object and I can't push converted dx source into scratch org with this option disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You can set this inside the org preferences.

OrgPreference.settings-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrgPreferenceSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <preferences>
        <settingName>ConsentManagementEnabled</settingName>
        <settingValue>true</settingValue>
    </preferences>
</OrgPreferenceSettings>
```

Easiest way to get this file is to add it to your package.xml under Settings if you are pulling from a sandbox or to actually create it as above and push into a scratch org - when you pull you should get all the other settings in there as well.

Comment: Adding this file causes my push to fail against my scratch org. Is this  the correct format?

Comment: Edited above to show how the whole file would look like and how to pull/retrieve this from a sandbox or scratch org.

Comment: This was perfect, I wish I could mark the answer as accepted for the OP. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

The **Data Protection and Privacy** preference can be automatically enabled via the scratch org definition file (e.g. project-scratch-def.json) using the `settings.orgPreferenceSettings.consentManagementEnabled` property.

```
{
    ...
    "settings: {
        "orgPreferenceSettings": {
            "consentManagementEnabled": true
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

However, according to the [Winter '20 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_api_meta_settings.htm), the **ConsentManagementEnabled** field on the  **OrgPreferenceSettings** metadata type will be moved to **enableConsentManagementEnabled** on **PartyDataModelSettings** instead, so be sure to update your configuration file in the future.

```
{
    ...
    "settings: {
        "partyDataModelSettings": {
            "enableConsentManagementEnabled": true
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

The ability to define org preferences in the scratch org definition file is available in Winter ’19 and later. This is detailed in the **Scratch Org Settings** section of the [Scratch Org Definition Configuration Values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) documentation. You can also find a list all settings in the [Settings Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_settings.htm) documentation. Be sure to use lower-case camel case when adding to the scratch org definition file.

Comment: One additional note is that if you use Individual object on another metadata like contact object's page layout as a look field, you need to deploy the PartyDataModel setting first in a separate deployment. Then you can push your changes related with the Individual object with a second deployment.